# Trouble passing parameters to an object java

Tags: java, arrays, object, parameters

I'm having trouble passing parameters to specify a specific attributes to an object to change that attribute. I'm a little new to objects and how they work. I need to use objects for this, as it's an assignment.

The purpose of this program is to basically store grades in an electronic gradebook. However, I have an object filled with names and quiz grades of hypothetical students. I need to create the setQuiz() method to grab a specified quiz value of the specified student, and then change it to specified grade. Here's what I have so far.

```
public class Student extends TestStudent
{
    public String name;
    public  int q1, q2, q3, q4, q5;
    public Student(String cName, int cq1, int cq2, int cq3, int cq4, int cq5 )
    {
        name = cName;
        q1 = cq1;
        q2 = cq2;
        q3 = cq3;
        q4 = cq4;
        q5 = cq5;
    }

    public void setQuiz(int grade, int quiz, int student) 
    {
        super.studentAr[student].{quiz?} = grade; 
        //Basically, I am not sure how to reference the exact grade I need 
        //to access, thus the question mark.
    }

}
```

So what do I do, StackOverflow? Do I need to totally rethink my structure here? Is it bad practice? Or am I on the right track and just missing something vital?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Create getter and setter for each of the student attributes. I believe that's what your teacher expect you to do

Comment: @DnR: That doesn't address accessing a quiz based on its index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this structure, the only way you can access each quiz is by referring to the quiz specifically. You can't just pass in a quiz number. You must do: student.q1, student.q2 etc.

Another thing that doesn't make sense is that you are passing the index of student into your setQuiz method. This method already belongs to a student object and there is only one object it can affect, which is itself. You need to choose which student to call the setQuiz method on in whatever location that you're calling it from.

EDIT: Changed the constructor to initialize all grades.

A better way to create your class would be as follows:

```
public class Student extends TestStudent
{
    public String m_name;
    public int[] m_grades;

    public Student(String cName, int q1, int q2, int q3, int q4, int q5)
    {
        m_grades = new int[5];
        m_grades[0] = q1;
        m_grades[1] = q2;
        m_grades[2] = q3;
        m_grades[3] = q4;
        m_grades[4] = q5;
    }

public void setQuiz(int grade, int quiz, int student)
    {
        if (quiz > 0 && quiz <= num_quizzes && grade >= 0 && grade < MAX_GRADE) //Always check yout inputs!!
        {
            super.studentAr[student].m_grades[quiz-1] = grade; 
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it form outside:

```
Student josh = new Student("Josh", 10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
josh.setQuiz(51, 1);
josh.setQuiz(60, 2);
josh.setQuiz(20, 3);
```

Or however you'd like to use it.. Up to you!

Another note. When you call super, in this case you are accessing an array on TestStudent class. I have not seen this class and I do not know if it has a studentAr[] member, but it shouldn't!
This array should be in another class that isn't inherited. It oculd be called StudentList or something like that.

EDIT: In response to your comment. If you need the grades to be accessed exactly as you stated, the only solution that comes to mind is:

```
public void setQuiz(int grade, int quiz, int student) 
{
    if (quiz == 1)
        super.studentAr[student].q1 = grade;
    if (quiz == 2)
        super.studentAr[student].q2 = grade;
    if (quiz == 3)
        super.studentAr[student].q3 = grade;
    if (quiz == 4)
        super.studentAr[student].q4 = grade;
    if (quiz == 5)
        super.studentAr[student].q5 = grade;
}
```

*Do note, however, that this is a fairly bad way of doing things. When I was handed assignments like this, I usually tried to do them right, impressed the teacher and walked away with an A+. Of course not all teachers appreciate this, so to stay safe you may want to prepare multiple answers - the specific one and the good one.*

Comment: This is really good and I appreciate it, but I need to stick to assigning grades in the object initially, rather than how you have it, as this is an assignment.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help. The way you put it the second time should work just fine. I think I understand it a bit better now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access on of a set of things by an index, you want to use an array, so you can use something like `q[quiz]`.

Comment: Is that possible to do when dealing with attributes of an object?

Comment: Make `q`, an array of `int`s, the attribute of the object.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb questions, but how would I fill an array from within an object, can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The same way you would from outside of one.